# Confusion integrating $\int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration, logarithms

I'm an A-Level further maths student (17 years old). There is some inconstancy in answers and I am not sure what is correct.

$$\int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\mathrm{d}x = [\ln |f (x)| \; \text{or} \; \ln (f(x))] + c$$

The mark schemes use sometimes $\ln |f (x)|$ and other times $\ln (f(x))$ as solutions to this integral and I don't know which to use and when. Is the modulus always needed or is it somehow dependent on $f$?

Note: $f$ is usually a polynomial of $x$.

Comment: As far as the usage of the absolute value is concerned: How did you learn how to integrate $1/x$dx?

Comment: If $f$ is non negative then both answers are the same. However, if we just know that $f\ne 0$ then $\ln|f(x)|$ is the correct answer, because we want an antiderivative at all points of our domain. If $f$ is negative at some point then $\ln(f(x))$ is not even defined there.

Comment: The modulus is technically always needed but you can ignore it if either $f(x)$ is always positive (for example, $f(x) = x^2 + 1$) or you restrict the domain to $x$ such that $f(x)$ is always positive. Also the meaning of "$+c$" becomes more subtle if $f$ has zeroes...

Comment: Mark and Qiaochu. Thank you very much both your answers. They were very helpful. I feel that I understand now.

Comment: Also, $c$ can have different values depending on the sign of $f$; it's a *locally constant* function of $x$.

Comment: In A levels the range tends to be quite clear, so if the domain $x\in[a,b]$ can be split such that $f(x)>0$ for $x\in[a,c]$ and $f(x)<0$ for $x\in[c,b]$ then you would only need to use the absolute part if you were interested in a domain including $[c,b]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the help in the comments. I wrote this answer and sent it to my teacher.

The question:

$$\int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\mathop{\mathrm{d}x} = \big[\ln |f (x)| \; \textbf{or} \; \ln (f(x))\big] + c$$

The first thing to note is that this is always true.

$$\int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\mathop{\mathrm{d}x} = \ln |f (x)| + c$$

The question we should be asking is not when does $\int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\mathop{\mathrm{d}x} = \ln (f (x)) + c$ but rather when is $\ln |f (x)| \equiv \ln (f (x))$ or more simply when is $|f(x)| \equiv f(x)$.

$|f(x)| \equiv f(x)$ only when $f(x)$ can only produce positive values. This can be achieved by having $f(x)$ raise $x$ to an even power.

$$\begin{aligned}\text{when }&\mathrm{Range}(f) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^+\\ &\text{then $|f(x)| \equiv f(x)$ 
} \\ &\text{then} \int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\mathop{\mathrm{d}x} = \ln (f (x)) + c \end{aligned}$$

For example:

$$\require{cancel}\begin{aligned}\int \frac{1}{x+3 }\mathop{\mathrm{d}x} &= \ln |\overbrace{x + 3}^{\tiny\text{can be negative}}| + c \\ & \not\equiv \xcancel{\ln (x + 3) + c} \\\\ \int \frac{2x}{x^2 + 1}\mathop{\mathrm{d}x} &= \ln |\overbrace{x^2 + 1}^{\tiny\text{always positive}}| + c \\ & \equiv \ln (x^2 + 1) + c
\end{aligned}$$

We can also exclude the modulus if the limits of our integral restrict the domain of $f$ so that the range of $f$ is always positive.

In summary

$$
    \int_b^a \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\mathop{\mathrm{d}x} = \left[
\begin{cases}
    \ln (f (x)),& \text{if } \ \{f(x): b\le x \le a\} \subseteq\mathbb{R}^+ \\
    \ln |f (x)|,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} + c \right]^a_b
$$